# How to put table under another table

Tags: html, alignment, html-table

how can I put one table under another if I have used align for example.

```
           center_table
left_table
           desired_table
```

But I am getting following result

```
           center_table
left_table desired_table
```

Here is my html code.
        
            
                center_table

```
    <table align="left">
        <tr>
            <td>left_table</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <table align="center">
        <tr>
            <td>desired_table</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Without using css only HTML

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add a `<div style = "clear:both;"></div>` in between your two tables. It should work then

The clear property specifies which side(s) of an element other floating elements are not allowed.

You can find more detail of it here http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_clear.asp

```
<table align="left">
  <table align="left">
    <tr>
        <td>left_table</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <div style="clear:both;"></div>

  <table align="center">
    <tr>
        <td>desired_table</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</table>
```

or

```
 <table align="left">
    <tr>
        <td>left_table</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <div style="clear:both;"></div>

  <table align="center">
    <tr>
        <td>desired_table</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

For the left aligned table change the width to 100% and it will work.

```
<table align="center" >
    <tr>
        <td>left_table</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table align="left" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td>left_table</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table align="center" >
    <tr>
        <td>desired_table</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Result -> http://jsfiddle.net/0LtqL8yh/embedded/result/

```
 <table border=1 width=80% height=30% align=left cellpadding=1 cellspacing=1>
        <tr height=30%>
            <td>First Row</td>
            <td>First Row</td>
            <td>First Row</td>
        </tr>
        <tr height=70%>
            <td>Second Row</td>
            <td>
                <table bgcolor=yellow border=1 width=80% height=80% align="center">
                    <tr>
                        <td>Inner Table</td>
                        <td>Inner Table</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Inner Table</td>
                        <td>Inner Table</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
            <td>Second Row</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```